# Make sure variable is array

Tags: javascript

I want to run `map()` on a variable that might either be a single object or an array. However, I can't do this if the variable is an object as that throws an error.

I tried using the spread operator to make sure the variable turns into an array but apparently that doesn't work either:

```
// items can either be an object or an array of objects
renderedItems = [...items]
    .filter(item => !!item)
    .map((item, index) => _this.renderItem(item, index));
```

How can I make sure the variable I'm doing a `filter()` and `map()` on is an array? I heard `Array.isArray` isn't fully supported yet.

Comment: Is the object array-like?

Comment: `Array.isArray` is widely supported now : https://caniuse.com/#search=isArray

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` to check if the variable is an Array.

```
if(variable instanceof Array){
  //variable is an Array
} else {
  //variable is not an Array
}
```

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var str = "String";
function isArray(obj){
 return obj instanceof Array;
}
console.log("array is an Array: "+isArray(array));
console.log("str is an Array: " + isArray(str));
```

You can also use `Array.isArray`.

```
if(Array.isArray(variable)){
 //variable is an Array
} else {
  //variable is not an Array
}
```

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var str = "String";
function isArray(obj){
    return Array.isArray(obj);
}
console.log("array is an Array: "+isArray(array));
console.log("str is an Array: " + isArray(str));
```

You can check if the variable's constructor is equal to Array.

```js
 var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var str = "String";
function isArray(obj){
        return obj.constructor === Array;
 }
 console.log("array is an Array: "+isArray(array));
console.log("str is an Array: " + isArray(str));
```